# Generate Header file for C code using python script

Tags: python, c

I am trying to generate a header file for C code using pyhton script.
I want to read some variables from csv file, the problem that i cant use libraries in the c code so i am not able to read the csv file from the c code.

I need to develop python script able to create a kind of simple input list to this C code.
Any suggestions ?

Comment: This would be a lot easier to understand if you shared some data from that CSV file, and told us a bit more what you mean when you say "some variables" (for example, do you mean plain-old-data, say integers and stuff, or something more elaborate?)

Comment: "i cant use libraries" Not even C standard library?

Comment: Please provide details (and sample data) about your input and desired output.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to read some variables from csv file, the problem that i cant use libraries in the c code so i am not able to read the csv file from the c code.

And you don't need to. Simply this is how the file gets generated:

```
[CSV File] -> Python -> [.h file]
```

So, you actually need to parse and convert the file in python, not in C.

## How to read CSV data in python?

You've got plenty of ways. My preference is reading it the simplest way. Consider your csv is just some floating point number lines:

```
with open('file.csv', 'r') as file:
    data = file.readlines()
rows = []
for line in data:
    rows.append([float(item.replace(' ', '')) for item in line.replace('\n', '')])
```

## How to generate header using extracted csv data?

Simply, it depends on you. It's not hard. Are you going to use 2d arrays?

Let me know if you've got any difficulties then I'll write a sample code for you. I don't find it hard to, though.

Comment: first thank you for your reply, i need to extract the data in 2d array but i don't know how to generate .h file. This .h file should contain the variables (array,...)  so i can include it in the C code. I know how to read from csv and extract information but how to convert this information to a varibales in a some sort of Header file that is what i don't know

Comment: You're welcome. I will modify the answer and add an example creating 2d arrays. By the way, is that a university class homework question? :)

Comment: thank you again,  it's not exactly  homework it's for my university project  i am trying to automate the environment :),  the c code will be executed but it's uncapable to handle libraries . while trying to configure a large bank of register i thought that will be more intelligent if i create csv with all this configuration using python then deliver it in  a header file as  input of this c code instead of spending time   on filling these configuration variables.